# How can EditText accept only integer or float value?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android development. In my project, I’m using EditText, but I want to force it to only accept an integer or float value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you want to use **Decimal Number** only on your `EditText`

use the xml attribute `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`  in your EditText widget
your `EditText` declaration will be like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

If you want to use **Signed Decimal Number** than combine the two Xml attributes `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` and  `android:inputType="numberSigned"`. Your `EditText` declaration will be like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" >

</EditText>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Java

for input both integer and float
`edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

for input only integer
`edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

Answer (score 0):

Currently using android tag:inputType is not enough.

See example https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/tree/student/Lesson06-Visualizer-Preferences/T06.10-Exercise-EditTextPreferenceConstraints

You need create a PreferenceChangeListener to verify the filled in EditText, before preference changed.