# Android Calculator - Editview cannot input decimal places

Tags: android, calculator

I am new to Android code development...I am developing a Android calculator apps and does not understand why the two EditTexts (first input and second input) cannot accept decimal places but can only input integers...Here attached as follows are the codes:

Thanks!

=============Main Activity===============================

```
package com.trial.jm4_calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView output;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
    }

View.OnClickListener btn1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       double opd1, opd2;
       double result = 0.0;
       EditText txtOpd1, txtOpd2;
       RadioButton rdbAdd, rdbSubtract, rdbMultiply, rdbDivide;
       CheckBox chkDivide;

       txtOpd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOpd1);
       txtOpd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtOpd2);

       opd1 = Double.parseDouble(txtOpd1.getText().toString());
       opd2 = Double.parseDouble(txtOpd2.getText().toString());

       rdbAdd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbAdd);
       if (rdbAdd.isChecked()) {
           result = opd1 + opd2;
       }
       rdbSubtract = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbSubtract);
       if (rdbSubtract.isChecked()) {
           result = opd1 - opd2;
       }
       rdbMultiply = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbMultiply);
       if (rdbMultiply.isChecked()) {
           result = opd1 * opd2;
       }
       rdbDivide = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbDivide);
       if (rdbDivide.isChecked()) {

              result = opd1 / opd2;            
       }
       output.setText("Answer = " + result);
    }
};
}
```

====================Main.xml===================================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="First Input: "/> 
        <EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:inputType="number" 
            android:id="@+id/txtOpd1"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <RadioGroup 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:id="@+id/rdgOp"> 
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="+ " 
            android:id="@+id/rdbAdd"/> 
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="- " 
            android:id="@+id/rdbSubtract"/> 
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="* " 
            android:id="@+id/rdbMultiply"/> 
        <RadioButton 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="/ " 
            android:id="@+id/rdbDivide"/> 
    </RadioGroup>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"> 
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Second Input: "/> 
            <EditText 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:inputType="number" 
                android:id="@+id/txtOpd2"/> 
     </LinearLayout> 
     <Button 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Compute" 
         android:id="@+id/button1"/> 
     <TextView 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/lblOutput"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can EditText accept only integer or float value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149881/how-can-edittext-accept-only-integer-or-float-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use **Decimal Number** only on your EditText

use the xml attribute `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` in your EditText widget your EditText declaration will be like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

If you want to use **Signed Decimal Number** than combine the two Xml attributes `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` and `android:inputType="numberSigned"`. Your EditText declaration will be like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" >

</EditText>
```

Comment: problem solved using the first one! many thanks!!
just would like to ask what is "signed Decimal Number"?

Comment: means the number can be negative

Comment: @pearmak your decimal number may be negative that's why you have to use numberSigned

Answer (score 3):

Change android:inputType from "number" to "numberDecimal". See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) for even more options for inputType.

Answer (score 1):

inputType="number" doesnt allow floats. try changing:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

to:

```
android:numeric="integer|decimal"
```

Comment: oh thanks! really so many kind of expressions for the codes that mess me up actually...this one without inputType wordings but I have tried and can run too..thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the input type of your EditText in the XML code.

Change the inputType attribute of the EditText from

`android:inputType="number"`

to

`android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

```
<EditText 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
            android:id="@+id/txtOpd1"/>
```